# What optimizations do modern JavaScript engines perform?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, jit

By now, most mainstream browsers have started integrating optimizing JIT compilers to their JavaScript interpreters/virtual machines. That's good for everyone. Now, I'd be hard-pressed to know exactly which optimizations they do perform and how to best take advantage of them. What are references on optimizations in each of the major JavaScript engines?

Background:

I'm working on a compiler that generates JavaScript from a higher-level & safer language (shameless plug: it's called [OPA](http://www.mlstate.com) and it's very cool) and, given the size of applications I'm generating, I'd like my JavaScript code to be as fast and as memory-efficient as possible. I can handle high-level optimizations, but I need to know more about which runtime transformations are performed, so as to know which low-level code will produce best results.

One example, from the top of my mind: the language I'm compiling will soon integrate support for laziness. Do JIT engines behave well with lazy function definitions?

Comment: Personally, I think the best way to take advantage of compiler/jit optimisations is to just generate your code as naturally, as readable, and as maintainable as possible and let the compiler/jit work it's magic. Any attempt to specifically target compiler optimisations will likely result in less maintainable code, and in a year or two when the compilers have all been changed, your optimizations will no longer be valid.

Comment: Well, readable/maintainable code is not really my objective. I'm compiling from a language which is quite different from JS, so I don't expect anyone to do much reading on the generated JS.

As for JIT magic and invalidity of optimizations, well, yes, you have a point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This article series](https://web.archive.org/web/20120803054413/http://techon.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/HONSHI/20090106/163615/) discusses the optimisations of V8. In summary:

- It generates **native machine code** - not bytecode ([V8 Design Elements](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html#mach_code))
- **Precise** garbage collection ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Precise_vs._conservative_and_internal_pointers))
- **Inline caching** of called methods ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching))
- Storing **class transition** information so that objects with the same properties are grouped together ([V8 Design Elements](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html#prop_access))

The first two points might not help you very much in this situation. The third might show insight into getting things cached together. The last might help you create objects with same properties so they use the same hidden classes.

[This blog post](http://webkit.org/blog/214/introducing-squirrelfish-extreme/) discusses some of the optimisations of SquirrelFish Extreme:

- Bytecode optimizations
- Polymorphic inline cache (like V8)
- Context threaded JIT (introduction of native machine code generation, like V8)
- Regular expression JIT

[TraceMonkey is optimised via tracing](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/tracemonkey-overview/). I don't know much about it but it looks like it detects the type of a variable in some "*hot code*" (code run in loops often) and creates optimised code based on what the type of that variable is. If the type of the variable changes, it must recompile the code - based off of this, I'd say you should stay away from changing the type of a variable within a loop.

Comment: Precise garbage collection? ... :S

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll need to take a look at class transitions.

Now, on to the other browsers :)

Comment: V8 material read.
TM read.
SF read.

Side note: the SF techniques described look, well, kind of disappointing. Especially, as described, their Context Threading looks much dumber than most JIT techniques I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I found an additional resource:

- *[What does V8 do with that loop?](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/06/08/what-does-v8-do-with-that-loop)*