# what techniques are currently being imployed to speed up the next generation javascript engines?

Tags: javascript, jit, vm-implementation

I know a fair amount about the current javascript engines. What techniques have arisen in the intervening time? Please provide links to freely available information.

edit:

To clarify, I'm looking for new techniques that are being implemented or have recently been thought up for improving javascript execution speed.

Comment: +1'ing to even out the downvote, but a bit more detail would be nice. What time span you are referring to, for example

Comment: the time span is future technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript virtual machines in the future will have a method JIT and a tracing JIT like firefox 4 and JägerMonkey/TraceMonkey.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references that came from the top of my head:

- [V8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html)
- [Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki)
- [Spidermonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/)
- [Gecko](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aHome_Page)
- [accelerated compositing in Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome)
- [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)
- [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL)
- [installable web apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/)
- [crankshaft](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html)

Please notice that at this moment (in the modern browsers) javascript isn't the bottleneck anymore in execution speed of the page. now that that problem is solved a lot of the browser manufacturers are focusing more on other aspects in the process of bringing a page from the server to the user. For instance a lot of the graphically rich pages that are standard now would benefit from the power of modern GPU's. It is often overlooked but rendering a typical page now takes generally more time than executing its scripts.

Comment: yes, but I believe this is because of the way pages are written (not spend a long time executing javascript). As HTML5 becomes prolific and javascript (and computers) get quicker, this may well change.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of your question is answered here:  [What optimizations do modern JavaScript engines perform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055981/what-optimizations-do-modern-javascript-engines-perform/2056026#2056026)

Comment: +1, congratulations on coming the closest to answering the question. I know about those optimizations, I'm looking for future ones, but If nobody answers in a better way I'll give the bounty to you.

Answer (score 0):

They [use the GPU](http://blogs.nvidia.com/ntersect/2010/09/next-killer-app-for-gpus-internet-explorer-9-beta-launch.html).

Comment: GPU is used for rendering, not for JavaScript execution. Neither IE9 or FF4 use it for JS, and most likely never will, since JavaScript are single-threaded for the most part, and you can only gain boost in performance from using GPU for highly threaded operations.

Comment: or if you auto-vectorise code, (but that's quite an expensive operation to put in a JIT)

Answer (score 0):

General details can be found at wikipedia.org and more detail at the Sun microsystems website and its links to associated sites. Some techniques now in use with recent versions of IE and Firefox and other browsers are forms of dualprocess or multiprocess operating in their own control structure to enhance performance specifically and for improving the general browsing experience. The use of javascript is decreasing in some nations and increasing in others as the relevant public internet server population changes over time. Only when the javascript parsing and interpreting code is rewritten in a faster language or some form of multiprocess is introduced to code on the servers or operating in the user's computer will the speed increase.